# Get media info mgp25/Instagram-API

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I'm use `mgp25/Instagram-API`

How can l get instagram media information? I mean text, photo, tags

Code:

```
$ig->login($username, $password);
$info = $ig->media->getInfo("1985828714113602831_25025320");
```

And i got an error:

> Uncaught InstagramAPI\Exception\EmptyResponseException: No response from server. Either a connection or configuration error

also `$ig->media->getInfo($mediaId)->getItems()[0]->getMedia()` same error

Maybe you know other way to get info. 
In advance thanks for help

Comment: I think "1985828714113602831_25025320" is id of media.
Did you try to use **`pk`** to get media?

Comment: Just wondering if there is any update on this? Been searching for the way to get the $mediaId used in the mgp25  package with no luck. Would appreciate it if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will bring you closer to your goal

```
$infos = $ig->media->getInfo("1985828714113602831_25025320");
$info = json_decode($infos);
//print_r($info->items[0]->image_versions2->candidates[0]);

 echo'<img src="'.$info->items[0]->image_versions2->candidates[0]->url.'">';
```